# HTML5 canvas text resizes

Tags: html, canvas

This must be obvious to most of you, so sorry for asking, but how come when I change the width of my canvas my text resizes as well? And how can I prevent this from happening?

code used:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillText("text",10,10);
```

btw: before I get voted down / bashed at, I tried searching about this for like twenty minutes.. no results.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a font?

Comment: Yes I have. The same happens whatever font I use.

Comment: how are you changing the width of your canvas? setting a CSS style and setting the "width" attribute is different.

Comment: im setting it using css. This makes a difference?

Comment: that's your problem. set the width using a `width="800"` etc. setting a css makes the canvas scale/zoom.

Comment: thanks dude, I didnt know about this. Create an answer if you want some free points ;)

Comment: It's still a good question as to why the font size would be dependent on the canvas size when it's given in pixels.  If I set a font size, I don't expect it to change no matter what my canvas size.  But change it does.

Comment: @RonaldBarzell the problem is, when setting the css it scales the canvas, and everything drawn in it.

Comment: @kennypu: Thanks. So basically I get different behaviors if I use CSS or an inline tag, even though CSS is advertised as a replacement for inline tags.  $#@!#@! CSS.

Comment: Why would they make CSS do that, though? Only brings confusion to people.

Comment: @user1534664: Because CSS is an ugly hack.  What it was meant to do was a good idea; how it did it stinks to high heaven. Just look at what a pain CSS can be for even simple element alignments, and of course the cross-browser shenanigans.  And they wonder why some people still use tables for layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't re-sizing it using CSS You need to set the [context font](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-2dcontext-20100304/#dom-context-2d-font) like so.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/meaU2/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function drawText() {
    ctx.font = 'italic 20px Calibri';
    ctx.fillText("HELLO!", 100, 100);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    drawText()
});
drawText()​
```

If you are resizing the canvas element using css like the following example

```
canvas{
    width:200px;
}
```

Then theres not much you can do to fix it. When you resize the canvas using CSS you just stretch it, but the pixel density stays the same. You should never use css to resize the canvas element, rather you should be using the `width` and `height` properties via JS like I do in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might occur due to changing the attributes by using CSS. It seems that canvas gets re-scaled when you access its properties through css. I think your problem might be solved if you use this in your javascript code instead of changing it through css :

```
document.getElementById("yourCanvasId").height = 150; // height you want to change to
document.getElementById("yourCanvasId").width = 150; // width you want to change to
```

Same problem occurred with me. I did this and the problem was solved. Hope it helps !